# I want to covert simple query in laravel 5.2 Eloquent format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this SQL query that I would like to convert to Eloquent:

```
 $query = "(SELECT name, Heading, 'msg' as type FROM tbl_cms WHERE name LIKE '%" . 
       $keyword . "%' OR Heading LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
       UNION
       (SELECT name, channel, 'topic' as type FROM  tbl_dramas WHERE name LIKE '%" . 
       $keyword . "%' OR channel LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')";
```

My current Eloquent query looks like this:

```
$keyword = $request->get("term");
if ($keyword != '') {
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where("name", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere("Heading", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
    });
}
return view('search', ['title' => 'search' ,'query' => $query]);
```

How can I convert it successfully?

Comment: $keyword = $request->get("term");
     if ($keyword!='') {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where("name", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere("Heading", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
                 
            });
        }
        return view('search', ['title' => 'search' ,'query' => $query]);
    }

Comment: i doing this laravel code above

Comment: Edit your post and add the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query1 = \DB::table('tbl_cms')
    ->select(\DB::raw('name, Heading, msg AS type'))
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orWhere('Heading', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');

$query2 = \DB::table('tbl_dramas')
    ->select(\DB::raw('name, channel, topic AS type'))
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->orWhere('channel', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');

$result = $query1->union($query2)->get();
```

Comment: QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'msg' in 'field list' (SQL: (select name, Heading, msg AS type from `tbl_cms` where `name` LIKE %ary% or `Heading` LIKE %ary%) union (select name, channel, topic AS type from `tbl_dramas` where `name` LIKE %ary% or `channel` LIKE %ary%))

Comment: Can you provide a list of columns that you have in `tbl_cms`? It seems the table doesn't have a column named `msg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = DB::table('tbl_cms')
            ->select('name', 'Heading', 'msg as type')
            ->where('name', 'like', $keyword.'%')
            ->orwhere('Heading', 'like', $keyword.'%');

$data = DB::table('tbl_dramas')
            ->select('name', 'channel', 'topic as type')
            ->where('name', 'like', $keyword.'%')
            ->orwhere('channel', 'like', $keyword.'%')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyword = '%'.\Input::get('q').'%';

$query1 = \DB::table('tbl_cms')
    ->select(\DB::raw("name, Heading, 'msg' as 'type'"))
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', $keyword)
    ->orWhere('Heading', 'LIKE', $keyword);

$query2 = \DB::table('tbl_dramas')
    ->select(\DB::raw("name, channel, 'topic' as 'type'"))
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', $keyword)
    ->orWhere('channel', 'LIKE', $keyword);

$results = $query1->union($query2)->get();
```